# Method is java swing that clear a Jlist?

Tags: swing, jlist, jtextfield

Is there a method in Java swing that clear a JList and a JTextField?

for example I have a string in a Jlist and a string in a JtextField and I want to press a "cancel" button, what method do i need to have in the mouse Listener in order for the Jlist and JtextField to clear?

Answer (score 6):

For `JTextField` you can use the `setText("");` method. [See more here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

For `JList`  you can use the `setListData(new Object[0]);` method. If you want the list to stay but only remove the selection you can use the `clearSelection()` method. [See more here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)